# How to specify a file path using '~' in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, macos

If I do:

```
require 'inifile'

# read an existing file
file = IniFile.load('~/.config')
data = file['profile'] # error here

puts data['region']
```

I get an error here:

```
t.rb:6:in `<main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

It goes away if I specify an absolute path:

```
file = IniFile.load('/User/demo1/.config')
```

But I do not want to hardcode the location. How can I resolve `~` to a path in Ruby?

Comment: Try `IniFile.load(ENV['HOME']+'/.config')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ruby has a method for this case. It is [`File::expand_path`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#method-c-expand_path).

> Converts a pathname to an absolute pathname. Relative paths are referenced from the current working directory of the process unless dir_string is given, in which case it will be used as the starting point. The given pathname may start with a “~”, which expands to the process owner’s home directory (the environment variable HOME must be set correctly). **`“~user”` expands to the named user’s `home` directory.**

```
require 'inifile'

# read an existing file
file = IniFile.load(File.expand_path('~/.config'))
```

Comment: (Please ignore my last comment about problem. Your solution works like a charm)

Answer (score 3):

When given `~` in a path at the command line, the shell converts `~` to the user's home directory. Ruby doesn't do that.

You could replace `~` using something like:

```
'~/.config'.sub('~', ENV['HOME'])
=> "/Users/ttm/.config"
```

or just reference the file as:

```
File.join(ENV['HOME'], '.config')
=> "/Users/ttm/.config"
```

or:

```
File.realpath('.config', ENV['HOME'])
=> "/Users/ttm/.config"
```